# How to change the value of a data-attribute and a td in a table HTML e Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this table in html, and I load it with Php Laravel

```
<div class="form-row col-md-12">

    <table id="contacts" class="table table-striped">       
        <tbody>      
            <tr>    
                <th>Id</th>    
                <th>Cel</th>           
                <th>Tel</th>           
                <th>Email</th>  
                <th>Actions</th>                 
            </tr>   
            @if(isset($contacts) && count($contacts)>0)

            @foreach($contacts $c)  

            <tr>        
                <td class="inf" data-id="{{ $c->id }}">         {{ $c->id }}      </td>
                <td class="inf" data-cel="{{ $c->cel}}">   {{ $c->cel}} </td>          
                <td class="inf" data-tel="{{ $c->tel}}"> {{ $c->tel}}</td>         
                <td class="inf" data-email="{{ $c->email }}">       {{ $c->email }}   </td>        
                <td>             
                    <button class='btn btn-primary btnAlterarContato' type="button">Alterar</button>       
                </td>
            </tr>

            @endforeach

            @endif

        </tbody>        

    </table>

</div>
```

You can see that each row has its data attribute for creating data. I made a method that I can retrieve the data from the TD and alter them, however I can not change the data of the data. how do I change how information that is without data attribute?

```
$('.btnAlterarContato').click(function(){

  var Row= $(this).closest('tr');

  var Posicao = 1;
  // Switch: 1 = Id, 2 = Cel, 3 = Tel, 4 = Email

  Row.find('td').each(function(){   
    switch(Posicao)
    {
        case 2: $(this).text('new value ');   $(this).attr('data-cel', 'Hi'); 
        $(this).data('data-cel','Hi')  ;break;
    }
        Posicao++;
  });   
});
```

I have a repeat loop to walk on every table td, and in case position 2 is the value of cel, I would like to change your display item and your cell-date when I do $ (this) .text ('new value ') this works, but I can not change the mobile date, how do I do this?

Comment: You don't need the `data-` prefix when using the `data()` method. Just use `data('cel')` etc. Also note that this won't update the DOM, but jQuery data cache instead. So long as you use `data()` as both getter and setter this will not be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing `data` attribute use `.data()` like below:-

```
$(this).data('cel', 'Hi');
```

Note:- Once clear your browser cache and check